# How to redirect to url external example www.google.com

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm studing Asp.Net core web applications.
I successfully created a CRUD website.

In the site I want to create a link to an external URL, e.g., to www.google.com

Here, the link is created this way.

```
https://localhost:44311/pVagaDivulgar/details/www.google.com
expected: www.google.com

<a href=@ViewBag.link target="_blank" class="nav-link">Curso</a>
<a href=@item.VagadivulgarCurso1Navigation.CursoLink class="nav-link">Go</a>
```

I dont know if I have to set some properties to make it work.

```
@model SiteJob1.ViewModel.pVagaDivulgar.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "details";
}
<h1>Jobdetails</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.VMvagasdivulgar)
{
    <h4>@item.VagadivulgarVaga.VagaTitulo</h4>
}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th><th>Course</th><th>Link</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.VMvagasdivulgar)
            {
                <tr>
                   <td>
                        @item.VagadivulgarId
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.VagadivulgarCurso1Navigation.CursoNome
                    </td>
                    <td>
<a href=@ViewBag.link target="_blank" class="nav-link">Curso</a>
<a href=@item.VagadivulgarCurso1Navigation.CursoLink class="nav-link">Go</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i understand your problem if you need to open Url then write full url like https://toastguyz.com

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        ViewBag.link = "https://www.toastguyz.com";
        return View();
}
```

Comment: for external link it required